# errexit and pipe in bash

Tags: bash, error-handling

How to make script to `errexit` if error occurs in the middle of the pipe?

```
set -e
LINE="$( ssh server1 cat 1.log | tail -1 )"
```

I want to break execution of the script on the ssh connection failure or if `1.log` does not exists on the remote side.

How to stop the execution of the script if any of the participants of the pipe returns non-zero exit code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `set -o pipefail` and it will manage errors between pipes.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.